# Defining the logarithm of a function

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I have a contractible open subset $U$ of a smooth manifold $M$, and a smooth $f:U\to\mathbb C^*$ (I don't know if I need all of these properties, but it is what I am working with).

Can I define $\log(f):U\to\mathbb C$, such that $\exp\circ\log(f)=f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can define $\log(f)$ and it suffices that your open subset $U$ is simply connected and $f$ is continuous. What you are looking for is a lift $g$ of $f$ to the covering $\exp : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$; it follows from the [lifting property of coverings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Lifting_properties) that such a lift exists provided that $f_{\#}(\pi_1(U,u))$ is trivial, which is always satisfied if $U$ is simply connected. You also have that such a lifting is unique once you fix the image $g(u)$ of $u \in U$.